# d3.js Y axis doesn't extend to value

Tags: d3.js

I have a barchart which is populated by values from a JSON variable. The chart is dynamic because the values are retrieved from an SQL query by doing a count. So my data gets fed back in like :

```
[{"Fruit":"Apple","COUNT( Fruit )":"12"},{"Fruit":"Orange","COUNT( Fruit )":"6"},{"Fruit":"Pear","COUNT( Fruit )":"1"},{"Fruit":"Blank","COUNT( Fruit )":"1"},{"Fruit":"Pineapple","COUNT( Fruit )":"1"},{"Fruit":"Kiwi","COUNT( Fruit )":"1"}]
```

For the most part my graphs seem to be displaying properly. However some are returning values that exceed the Y Axis, I dont think it's the values that are causing the issues I believe its the axis that isnt calculating the right height. For instance

If Orange count is 14, sometimes the Y axis stops at a number less than this and that column extends the graph.

By viewing it in google chrome developer console, I can see the height of the bar is

```
<rect id="Orange" y="-520px" x="94px" height="1040px" width="162"></rect>
```

which far extends my SVG height of 600px - Margins(top + bottom) of 80px!

Does anyone know why my Y Axis isn't getting the right Max value?

Code here:

```
                var canv = document.getElementById("exportCanvas");
                canv.width  = screen.width;
                var margin ={top:40, right:0, bottom:40, left:40},
                    width=screen.width - 250,
                    height=600-margin.top-margin.bottom;


                var jsplit =  jdata.split('"');
                var keyX = jsplit[1];
                var keyY = "";
                var data = JSON.parse(jdata);
                for (k in data[0]) {
                    if (k!=keyX) keyY=k;
                }
                console.log("keyX = " + keyX);


                console.log(keyY);
                console.log(data[0]);




                // scale to ordinal because x axis is not numerical
                var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain(['Orange','Apple','Pear'])  //Added this in temporarilly. this should be calculated from the data. 
                    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.25,0.25);

                //scale to numerical value by height
               // var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

                var y = d3.scale.linear()

                    .range([height, 0]);


                console.log(data);
                x.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d[keyX]}));


                y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d[keyY]})]);   

                var chart = d3.select("#chart")
                    .append("svg")  //append svg element inside #chart
                    .attr("width", width+ margin.left+margin.right)    //set width
                   // .attr("width", width+(2*margin.left)+margin.right)    //set width
                    .attr("height", height+margin.top+margin.bottom); //set height

                   // .attr("transform", "translate(" + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + "," + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + ")");


                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom");  //orient bottom because x-axis will appear below the bars

                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .orient("left")
                    .ticks(10).tickFormat(function(d) {
                        if (d % 1 == 0) {
                            return d3.format('.f')(d)
                        } else {
                            return ""
                        }
                    });

                var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
                        .data(data)
                        .enter()
                        .append("g");

                        //you're moving the group and then moving the rect below as well
                        //one or the other not both need to be moved. 
                        //.attr("transform", function(d, i){
                        //    return "translate("+x(d[keyX])+", 0)";
                        //});

                    bar.append("rect")
                        .attr("id", function(d) {
                            return d[keyX];
                        }) 
                        .attr("y", function(d) {
                            return y(d[keyY]) + "px";
                        })
                        .attr("x", function(d,i){
                           //AB - Adjusted this so it correcly places the bar along the X
                           //x.range is an array of x values for each bar
                           //calculated in the var x = line above , with the .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.25,0.25);
                           //setting the width of the bars (an equal division of width) with margins of 0.25 at the start
                           //and end of the graph and 0.25 between each bar.
                           return x.range()[i] + margin.left + "px";
                        })


                        .attr("height", function(d) {
                            return height - y(d[keyY]) +"px";

                        })


                        .attr("width", x.rangeBand());  //set width base on range on ordinal data

                    bar.append("text")
                        .attr("x",function(d,i){
                            //similar to above but adding half the width of the bar to the x position 
                            //to roughly center it on the bar. only rough as doesnt take account of length of text.
                            return x.range()[i] + margin.left + (x.rangeBand()/2)+ "px";
                        })
                        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[keyY]) +20; })
                        .attr("dy", ".75em")
                        .style("fill","white")
                        .style("font-weight", "bold")
                        .text(function(d) { return d[keyY]; });

                    chart.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "x axis")
                        .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+","+ height+")")
                        .call(xAxis);


                    chart.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "y axis")
                        .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+",0)")
                        .call(yAxis)
                        .append("text")
                        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                        .attr("y", 6)
                        .attr("dy", ".71em")
                        .style("text-anchor", "end")
                        .text(keyY);
```

Apologies for commented out code, I have been playing with it alot to try and suss this out.

Comment: can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't access that site on the network im on unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

You need to recalculate y.domain() when your dataset refreshes.  So when you update your data, you can try something like:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d[keyY]})]);    
chart.select(".y.axis")
    .call(yAxis.scale(y));
```

Comment: Sorry Seemant, where abouts would this go. All the above code is generated in an AJAX success function. So everytime a button is clicked it goes off to the database with 3 variables, returns some data and then creates the chart. The contents of the <svg> tag is changed when the new data is loaded in.

Comment: Hi @DanW, Are you able to put an example of this on blockbuilder.org by any chance?  You might consider binding the button click event from d3, rather than putting all this code into an AJAX success function.  That way, d3 can handle the click event and perform an update() to the existing graph, rather than re-creating the SVG on each click. Forgive me, if I'm misunderstanding the mechanics of your vis.

Comment: I think the reason I put it within the AJAX success was to retrieve the data from that ajax success and then use it directly in the d3 bar chart. I can see if blockbuilder is an option but the network is very restricted.

Comment: I've tried to get blockbuilder working, It's accessible via the network but shows a blank screen with the code I've copied in with Data that has been manually set.

Comment: Let's start with what you've got, if you can put the link here.

Comment: http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/5e0bf6568e248607be85 try that, i think that is it.

Comment: http://blockbuilder.org/seemantk/2c6fbecc295523032522  I had to make some adjustments -- the data as you've written it does not need to be JSON parsed, and I dispensed with some of the processing, in favour of using the clunky field name "COUNT( Fruit )".  If you have any control of that, I suggest changing that key name to be something better, like just Count.  The graph works for me...

Comment: I see, the data that I will be retrieving will need parsing, I simply put that in as placeholder data. The field name is just what is passed back by the SQL query. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to show my problem on blockbuilder. Which is a little bit irritating because It is showing on my own version. Also all the areas where you have replaced with the field name as it is "known" will have to be dynamic as they are in my original code, ripping the values out of the JSON data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106711/discussion-between-seemant-kulleen-and-dan-w).

Comment: restriction of the network can't use chat ! :( I can try on my phone.